# Error while trying to assign a string value to a pandas dataframe using .at[]

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd

SGFile = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Python scripts\SG Title\SG\JW\03_02_2020\SG_Final_Combined_test.xlsx")

OldExtract = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Title Database\oldExtract_test.xlsx")

for row in SGFile.itertuples():
    if pd.isna(row.Country_Origin):
        Subdata = OldExtract[OldExtract.Title_Main == row.Title_Main]
        for Subdatarow in Subdata.index:
            pos = Subdatarow
            break; 

        CountryOrigin = Subdata.at[pos,'Country_Origin_1']

        SGFile.at[row.Index,'Country_Origin'] = CountryOrigin
```

The error occurs at line  `SGFile.at[row.Index,'Country_Origin'] = CountryOrigin`

Below is the error:

```
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'United States of America'
```

It works fine if i try to assign an integer value, however throws an error when assigning a string type.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: probably means that the column is not a string data type. you could check the column's dtype to be sure

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy..... that was the issue...chnaged it to str and it worked fine